# Angular and non shared services

Tags: angularjs

I know that angular services are singeltons but I have an application in which I want that each directive instance will have a different service object which will hold context. How can it be achived?

Comment: Can you paste some code of what you try to achieve?

Comment: currently i dont have code cause I want to know that my idea can work. but i want to have directive that has a controller. from the other side i want to have an angular service which communicate with require. this service should hold the context to each directive

Answer (score 0):

You can use a factory that returns the constructor the class that you need, later just inject it to the controller and instantiate it.

```
app.factory('demoClass', function() {
   return { 
          sayHello : function() { console.log('hello') }
          }
});
```

At controller:

```
function myController($scope, demoClass)
{
  var test = new demoClass();
  test.sayHello();
}
```